# Manipulate data from angular JSON response

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a standard JSON response in an Angular controller, which returns data.

I am trying to get specific parts of that data, and manipulate it and use the manipulated version within the code.

Currently i have:

```
$http.get('/json/file.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.results = data;    
});
```

In the JSON, i have data such as this:

```
"hotels":[  
    { 
        "region": "Indian Ocean"
    }
]
```

In my code, i am using ng-repeat to call "hotel in results.hotels" and using "hotel.region".

How do i grab the hotel.region from the data, and remove the space between the words, replace the space with a '_' and make it all lower case so i end up with "indian_ocean".  As well as this, how would i then use this within my ng-repeat?

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
data.hotels[0].region.replace(" ","_").toLowercase()
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just do...

```
$scope.results.forEach(function (element) {element.replace(" ","_").toLowercase()});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so this can be used in a more general way.

Create a new filter...

```
app.filter('removeSpaces', function () {
    return function (text) {
     var str = text.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
     return str.toLowerCase();
    };
});
```

Then this can be used site-wide by calling "{{hotel.region | removeSpaces}}".

Thanks to the people who did respond and for their help.